# User defined shape of buttons for GUI using MFC

Tags: user-interface, mfc

Do we have the flexibility to have user defined shapes for various elements of a GUI created with MFC? For example can I develop a GUI using MFC, with menus similar to [this one](http://www.webdeveloperjuice.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/apple.jpg) ?

Comment: For example, for paste option, can I use a small icon like this: [link](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/images/used-in-examples/mainwindows/application/images/paste.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. There are several ways, the most hardcore one is using SetWindowRgn() - that way you have exact control over the shape of the window, but no per-pixel alpha. You can also use one of the many classes available on CodeProject that does this. You can also have a look at the Ultimate Toolbox which is quite old but may contain something that is enough for your needs. You can also use the SetLayeredWindow() API's, which give you per-pixel alpha. Start with http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997507.aspx and then search for the keyword on CodeProject for controls that take away the drudgery for you. Or, look into modern toolkits like Codejock etc. which aren't free but which may save you lots of time, depending on what and how many effects exactly you want to incorporate into your application.